Is it true that the ark caused armies to be wiped out when taken to the battlefield?
I was reading an article online about the riches the templars stole from the temple of Solomon, the templars were suposedly looking for the Ark of Covenant which is written in scripture that when taken to the battlefield could wipe out entire armies. But then they never found the  ark of covenant because it was lost alongside the tablets given to Moses after the Babylonians invaded the promised land. Had the tempars succeeded in finding it, do you think if they could have taken it to the battlefield, it would have wiped out entire armies?
You can read about the templar digging up riches from the temple from this site

This is just mythology. The superstition of the medieval Romans about holy grail, and Ark of covenant etc and their innovative relic art manufacturing for religious use is unrelated to theology.

This question is way too speculative to be answered. The powers of the ark of the covenant are not a question of the belief of any one Christian group.

Read Exodus ch25 for a description of the construction of the ark.

@Michael16, but is it true that the ark wiped out enemies ?

@AlbertusMagnus I’m saying that the powers of the ark are not the doctrine of any one Christian group. It is purely left to the speculation of each individual (really Christian or otherwise)

The Ark was used to kill enemies, but it cannot be used as a magic charm weapon that anyone possess it will have the super powers. That are things which the youtubers or history channel type people would use.

much of those supernatural events surrounding the ark (deaths/ used as weapon) are clearly mythological in itself. So, you need to rightly divide the genres and literature before jumping to conclusions on the line of the history tv or youtube documentaries.

@Michael16, the events are not mythology to believers because you cannot believe half scripture and say the other half is mythology then you are not a believer, are you a believer?

that is not true for many. I am a believer. If you read good study bibles, there are essays and notes pointing to such things and you should read the works of contributing scholars. It is not necessary to take every written thing as historical. Understand them in their original literary context. This is not a view of atheists only.

@Michael16, then why do ye say that these supernatural events are mythological? They would not be a myth to a believer?

I am saying that it is not necessary that believers take all such accounts as historical. You need to read some details about ancient historiography. They respected myths and did not focus on scientific historicity/truthfulness. The scientific view began only in the recent 2-3 centuries.

@Michael16, the Bible is not a myth to me but a self Revelation of God to me and I have evidence though a personal experience that he lives, so if the same spirit that called me by name through the mouth of a stranger is the same spirit that inspired the authors to write the Bible, I believe in every iota

No. The ark was present at battles where God gave Israel a miraculous victory. The ark did not in and of itself cause the miracle.
The first evidence for this is in 1 Samuel 4. The faithless Jews lost the ark during battle. If it unconditionally granted such powers to its possessors as some claim, they would not have suffered thirty thousand casualties.
The second evidence is during the reign of Hezekiah. A large, Assyrian army was camped outside. If the ark could cause such damage, why did he not send the ark out into the battlefield? The Lord did deliver Judah from that great army via a plague.
Third, Hezekiah's attitude toward the power of holy relics is demonstrated here:

He did what was right in the eyes of the Lord, just as his father
David had done. 4 He removed the high places, smashed the sacred
stones and cut down the Asherah poles. He broke into pieces the bronze
snake Moses had made, for up to that time the Israelites had been
burning incense to it. (It was called Nehushtan.) (2 Kings 18:3-4)

Hezekiah destroyed a relic rather than permit people to worship it.
It is true that while the Philistines possessed the ark, they suffered tumors, perhaps cancer. This led to them returning the Ark with an offering to appease God, as recounted in 1 Samuel 6. This has lead to speculation that the Ark was radioactive, hence some sort of energy weapon.
It was God's wrath at the desecration of one of His symbols that led to the plague against the Philistines, not an innate power within the Ark.

Yeah the fact they lost the ark when Gid was not on their side proves it l.
